# Elastic Beanstalk on a naked domain?

Tags: amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk

If I were to be using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a cluster of servers, it creates a load balancer for me.

The advice is to specify an A record pointing to the Elastic Beanstalk name provided (appname.elasticbeanstalk.com), however you cannot specify an A record on the naked domain (http://myapp.com), and would have to be set on http://www.myapp.com.

However the load balancer that it creates shows up and can be used as an alias inside Route53 for an A record and it seems that I could apply this to the naked domain. My question is, is there any circumstance under which that load balancer would get removed or modified and break my DNS entries, except for my terminating that environment? If I were to do this, it's obviously critically important that it would survive application updates, additional servers being created etc.

Alternatively, is there a workaround which would allow me to use Elastic Beanstalk as the target for my naked domain?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Elastic Beanstalk just launched support for aliasing to your environment[1].  I would recommend doing that instead of aliasing directly to your ELB.

1. https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk/0946276467984605

Comment: So to confirm, this support would allow me to add an A-record alias to the Elastic Beanstalk environment, which would solve the problem? And there's no reason for that to require manual changing unless I fully terminate the environment, it will persist through application updates, changing of the underlying EC2 instances etc? That would solve it so I hope that's accurate!

Comment: That's correct, those are all the reasons why you would alias to your environment directly and not a specific resource, such as your elb.